# Spring-boot application deploying issue

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I created a spring-boot application using a tutorial and it was built successfully using 'mvn clean install' command. After that I execute the 'mvn spring-boot:run' command to run the application and it also successfully deployed. However, when I was loading the page on the browser by hitting http://localhost:8080/api, it always redirects to http://localhost:8080/login which I had deployed a few months ago. How should I delete deployment related to http://localhost:8080/login?

my controller class is as follows,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import mat.pathini.model.Customer;
import mat.pathini.repo.CustomerRepository;



@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerController {

  @Autowired
  CustomerRepository repository;

  @GetMapping("/customers")
  public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
    System.out.println("Get all Customers...");

    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    repository.findAll().forEach(customers::add);

    return customers;
  }

  @PostMapping("/customer")
  public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {

    Customer _customer = repository.save(new Customer(customer.getName(), customer.getAge()));
    return _customer;
  }

  @DeleteMapping("/customer/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<String> deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    System.out.println("Delete Customer with ID = " + id + "...");

    repository.deleteById(id);

    return new ResponseEntity<>("Customer has been deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @GetMapping("customers/age/{age}")
  public List<Customer> findByAge(@PathVariable int age) {

    List<Customer> customers = repository.findByAge(age);
    return customers;
  }

  @PutMapping("/customer/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Customer> updateCustomer(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Customer customer) {
    System.out.println("Update Customer with ID = " + id + "...");

    Optional<Customer> customerData = repository.findById(id);

    if (customerData.isPresent()) {
      Customer _customer = customerData.get();
      _customer.setName(customer.getName());
      _customer.setAge(customer.getAge());
      _customer.setActive(customer.isActive());
      return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.save(_customer), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
  }
}
```

The tutorial that I followed is,
https://grokonez.com/frontend/vue-js/spring-boot-vue-js-example-spring-data-jpa-rest-mysql-crud

Logs as follows

```
>     Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1
> .1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry
> /2.0.8/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.8.jar (29 kB at 7.8 kB/s) Downloading
> from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/collections/google-collect
> ions/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.
> 1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar (45 kB at 10 kB/s) Downloading from
> central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2
> .8.1/plexus-archiver-2.8.1.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbe
> an-reflect-3.4.jar (134 kB at 29 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.3.2/p
> lexus-io-2.3.2.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-d
> efault/1.5.5/plexus-container-default-1.5.5.jar (217 kB at 47 kB/s)
> Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-
> plugin/2.2/maven-shade-plugin-2.2.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
> (3 58 kB at 76 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-compat/3.0/mav
> en-compat-3.0.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/collections/google-collecti
> ons/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar (640 kB at 130 kB/s) Downloading
> from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider
> -api/1.0-beta-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-6.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.
> 8.1/plexus-archiver-2.8.1.jar (143 kB at 29 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
> Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.3.2/pl
> exus-io-2.3.2.jar (74 kB at 15 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-commons/3.3.1/asm-commons-3.3
> .1.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-p
> lugin/2.2/maven-shade-plugin-2.2.jar (100 kB at 20 kB/s) Downloading
> from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-tree/3.3.1/asm-tree-3.3.1.jar
> 
> Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-compat/3.0/mave
> n-compat-3.0.jar (285 kB at 54 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
> Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-
> api/1.0-beta-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-6.jar (53 kB at 9.9 kB/s)
> Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-depende
> ncy-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar (44
> kB at
> 8.1 kB/s) Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/vafer/jdependency/0.7/jdependency
> -0.7.jar Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-commons/3.3.1/asm-commons-3.3.
> 1.jar (38 kB at 7.0 kB/s) Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-tree/3.3.1/asm-tree-3.3.1.jar
> (22 kB at 3.9 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-i
> o-1.3.2.jar Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2
> .jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/vafer/jdependency/0.7/jdependency-
> 0.7.jar (12 kB at 2.0 kB/s) Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.jar
> Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
> (153 kB  at 26 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-1
> 1.0.2.jar Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependen
> cy-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar (60 kB at 10 kB/s)
> Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.
> jar (18 kB at 3.0 kB/s) Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io
> -1.3.2.jar (88 kB at 15 kB/s) Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.jar
> (37 kB at 5.8 kB/s) Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11
> .0.2.jar (1.6 MB at 222 kB/s) [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @
> spring-boot-restapi-mysql --- Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom
> Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom
> (998  B at 2.5 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commo
> ns-codec-1.6.pom Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/common
> s-codec-1.6.pom (11 kB at 25 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/22/
> commons-parent-22.pom Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/22/c
> ommons-parent-22.pom (42 kB at 97 kB/s) Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-
> utils/0.4/maven-shared-utils-0.4.pom Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-u
> tils/0.4/maven-shared-utils-0.4.pom (4.0 kB at 5.0 kB/s) Downloading
> from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
> Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.
> 15/plexus-utils-3.0.15.jar Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-
> utils/0.4/maven-shared-utils-0.4.jar Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commo
> ns-codec-1.6.jar Downloading from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/c
> lassworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/cl
> assworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar (38 kB at 65 kB/s) Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
> (121  kB at 170 kB/s) Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/common
> s-codec-1.6.jar (233 kB at 271 kB/s) Downloaded from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-u
> tils/0.4/maven-shared-utils-0.4.jar (155 kB at 175 kB/s) Downloaded
> from central:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.1
> 5/plexus-utils-3.0.15.jar (239 kB at 253 kB/s) [INFO] Installing
> D:\MyWork\Project\Pathini\matrimonial-api\target\spring-boot-restapi-mysql-0.0.1-S
> NAPSHOT.jar to
> C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\grokonez\spring-boot-restapi-mysql\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\sp
> ring-boot-restapi-mysql-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar [INFO] Installing
> D:\MyWork\Project\Pathini\matrimonial-api\pom.xml to
> C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\
> com\grokonez\spring-boot-restapi-mysql\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\spring-boot-restapi-mysql-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 03:54 min [INFO] Finished at:
> 2019-09-07T11:45:05+08:00 [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> D:\MyWork\Project\Pathini\matrimonial-api>mvn spring-boot:run [INFO]
> Scanning for projects... [INFO] [INFO] ---------------<
> com.grokonez:spring-boot-restapi-mysql >--------------- [INFO]
> Building SpringBootRestMySQL 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
> --------------------------------[ jar ]--------------------------------- [INFO] [INFO] >>>
> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) >
> test-compile @ spring-boot-res tapi-mysql >>> [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @
> spring-boot-restapi-mysql --
> - [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 1 resource [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @
> spring-boot-restapi-mysql --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes
> are up to date [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @
> spring-boot-restapi- mysql --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy
> filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @
> spring-boot-restapi-mysql  --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes
> are up to date [INFO] [INFO] <<<
> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) <
> test-compile @ spring-boot-res tapi-mysql <<< [INFO] [INFO] [INFO] ---
> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @
> spring-boot-restapi-mysql ---
> 
>   .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __
> _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
> =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)
> 
> 2019-09-07 11:55:59.573  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> SpringBootRestMySqlApplication           : Starting
> SpringBootRestMySqlApplication on HP-PC with PID 7692
> (D:\MyWork\Project\Pathini\matrimonia l-api\target\classes started by
> User in D:\MyWork\Project\Pathini\matrimonial-api) 2019-09-07
> 11:55:59.587  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> SpringBootRestMySqlApplication           : No active profile set,
> falling back to default profiles: default 2019-09-07 11:55:59.689 
> INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationC
> ontext@7c851b1f: startup date [Sat Sep 07 11:55:59 SGT 2019]; root of
> context hierarchy 2019-09-07 11:56:00.698  WARN 7692 --- [          
> main] o.s.b.a.AutoConfigurationPackages        :
> @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the default
> package. Automatic @Repository and @ Entity scanning is not enabled.
> 2019-09-07 11:56:01.254  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
> 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
> of type [o
> rg.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringC
> GLIB$$81417af9] is not eligible for getting processed by all
> BeanPostProcessors (for example: not el igible for auto-proxying)
> 2019-09-07 11:56:02.102  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with
> port(s): 8080 (http) 2019-09-07 11:56:02.141  INFO 7692 --- [         
> main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service
> [Tomcat] 2019-09-07 11:56:02.141  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine:
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.34 2019-09-07 11:56:02.153  INFO 7692 ---
> [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR
> based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
> production environmen ts was not found on the java.library.path:
> [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Ja
> va\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs
> \;D:\MyWork\Project\spring-2.0.4.RELEASE\bin;%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program
> Files\A pache\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C
> :\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;D:\MyW
> ork\Project\spring-2.0.4.RELEASE\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
> ;D:\MyWork\Project\spring-2.0.4.RELEASE\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\
> nodejs\;D:\MyWork\Project\spring-2.0.4.RELEASE\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program 
> Files\nodejs\;D:\MyWork\Project\spring-2.0.4.RELEASE\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\ProgramData\chocola
> tey\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Apache\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd ;C:\Program
> Files\PuTTY\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Apache\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bi
> n;C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Apache\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Pr ogram
> Files\PuTTY\;D:\MyWork\Project\spring-2.0.4.RELEASE\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin ;C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\;D:\MyWork\Project\spring-2.0.4.RELEASE\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_
> 131\bin;C:\Program;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\bin;.] 2019-09-07 11:56:02.271  INFO 7692 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> embedded WebApplicationContext 2019-09-07 11:56:02.272  INFO 7692 ---
> [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root
> WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2588 ms 2019-09-07
> 11:56:02.431  INFO 7692 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
> 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 2019-09-07 11:56:02.432  INFO 7692
> --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*] 2019-09-07
> 11:56:02.432  INFO 7692 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
> 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*] 2019-09-07 11:56:02.432  INFO 7692
> --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*] 2019-09-07
> 11:56:02.433  INFO 7692 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter:
> 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*] 2019-09-07 11:56:02.434  INFO
> 7692 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  :
> Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/] 2019-09-07 11:56:02.650  INFO
> 7692 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       :
> HikariPool-1 - Starting... 2019-09-07 11:56:02.889  INFO 7692 --- [   
> main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start
> completed. 2019-09-07 11:56:02.956  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2019-09-07
> 11:56:02.980  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
> PersistenceUnitInfo [
>         name: default
>         ...] 2019-09-07 11:56:03.099  INFO 7692 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core
> {5.2.17.Final} 2019-09-07 11:56:03.101  INFO 7692 --- [          
> main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206:
> hibernate.properties not found 2019-09-07 11:56:03.161  INFO 7692 ---
> [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   :
> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 2019-09-07
> 11:56:03.313  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect:
> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 2019-09-07 11:56:03.664  INFO 7692
> --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> 2019-09-07 11:56:03.798  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path
> [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resour ce.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
> 2019-09-07 11:56:04.089  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for
> @ControllerAdvice:
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletW
> ebServerApplicationContext@7c851b1f: startup date [Sat Sep 07 11:55:59
> SGT 2019]; root of context hi erarchy 2019-09-07 11:56:04.155  WARN
> 7692 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration :
> spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database
> queries may be performed during v iew rendering. Explicitly configure
> spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning 2019-09-07
> 11:56:04.219  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto
> public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.Stri
> ng, java.lang.Object>>
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController
> .error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) 2019-09-07 11:56:04.221 
> INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped
> "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public
> org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView or
> g.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.
> http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
> 2019-09-07 11:56:04.590  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path
> [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.R esourceHttpRequestHandler]
> 2019-09-07 11:56:04.591  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto
> handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceH ttpRequestHandler]
> 2019-09-07 11:56:05.063  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :
> 
> 
> Using generated security password:
> 994acd24-ee2a-4142-9514-90abd9626efc
> 
> 2019-09-07 11:56:05.276  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain:
> org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1,
> [org.sprin
> gframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6cae2294,
> org.springf
> ramework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@590e1be3,
> org.springframework.securit y.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@63e37b1a,
> org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7b9b58ea, 
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@901cc19,
> org.springframework.se
> curity.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5bb94950,
> org.springframework.securit
> y.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@37b2a2c6,
> org.springframework.security.web.
> authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@12bbd6aa,
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest
> .RequestCacheAwareFilter@2dc9fd87,
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolder
> AwareRequestFilter@53ad8be3,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthentication
> Filter@f357d9f,
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1440774b,
> org.sprin
> gframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1186a99c,
> org.springframework.security.web
> .access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@625c3443] 2019-09-07
> 11:56:05.405  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX
> exposure on startup 2019-09-07 11:56:05.408  INFO 7692 --- [          
> main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name
> 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure 2019-09-07
> 11:56:05.416  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource':
> registering with JMX server as MBean
> [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource, type=HikariDataSource] 2019-09-07
> 11:56:05.465  INFO 7692 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s):
> 8080 (http) with context path '' 2019-09-07 11:56:05.471  INFO 7692
> --- [           main] SpringBootRestMySqlApplication           : Started SpringBootRestMySqlApplication in 6.497 seconds (JVM running
> for 10.695) 2019-09-07 11:58:53.412  INFO 7692 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2019-09-07 11:58:53.413  INFO
> 7692 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
> FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
> 2019-09-07 11:58:53.454  INFO 7692 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet
> 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 40 ms
```

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Comment: @emotionlessbananas Thanks for the advice. All the codes are here.  https://grokonez.com/frontend/vue-js/spring-boot-vue-js-example-spring-data-jpa-rest-mysql-crud.

Comment: ok,  post the logs

Comment: @emotionlessbananas I don't have log file, but I attached the logs that display on console.

Comment: in your pom.xml you have added `spring-starter-security`, remove it

Comment: @chk.buddi ,it seems you have added spring security in your project. Btw, do you get what you want after login?

Comment: yes, you will...

Comment: Thanks for all, it works  fine after removing spring-security.

Comment: I am posting this as an answer please accept it if that worked for you so this question can be closed

Comment: @emotionlessbananas ok, I’ll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete or comment your dependency "Spring Security" in pom.xml. Because it automatically adds to your Application default /login page for authentication(without configurations and users to login(only generated "user" + "password in your console")).

Comment: After deleting spring-security, it gives a different error. I asked that error in a different thread. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836100/this-may-be-the-result-of-an-unspecified-view-due-to-default-view-name-generati

Answer (score 1):

In your project you have added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now, In order to make it work for production you may have to configure it properly but since you are following tutorial, which leaves you with 2 options, i.e.

either remove this dependency or use default password which is being printed on console, every time you run your application.

**Default username:**

> **user**

**Default password:**

> Using generated security password:
>
> **994acd24-ee2a-4142-9514-90abd9626efc**

**NOTE** this password changes every time you re-run your application and always check console logs for new password

Comment: After deleting spring-security,it solved above issue but now, it gives a different error. I asked that error in a different thread. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836100/this-may-be-the-result-of-an-unspecified-view-due-to-default-view-name-generati