# This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

When running my spring-boot + Vue js application(I followed [this](https://grokonez.com/frontend/vue-js/spring-boot-vue-js-example-spring-data-jpa-rest-mysql-crud#12_Data_Model) tutorial to build this app), I got the following error at the beginning.

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:209)
```

To solve the issue, I added the following dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now I'm getting the following error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of t
he configured Template Resolvers
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:870) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:354) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:187) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5
.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEAS
E]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEA
SE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: Share your view resolver bean configuration

Comment: @emotionlessbananas I don't have view resolver bean as I use Spring-boot. Whole application has done using this tutorial.  https://grokonez.com/frontend/vue-js/spring-boot-vue-js-example-spring-data-jpa-rest-mysql-crud#12_Data_Model

Comment: So how your application will know that you are using thymeleaf?

Comment: You don't need to do extra configuration, just move all your views inside `src/main/resources/templates` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the thymeleaf autoconfiguration through the `application.yml` or `application.properties` .

```
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
```

alsi add the prefix and suffix in yml or property file as required. Or you could manually configure the view resolver like :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        var templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return templateResolver;
    }

   @Bean
   public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
       SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
       templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
       templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
       return templateEngine;
   }

   @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
       var viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();   
       viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
       viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       return viewResolver;
    }
}
```